# Configuring Host Name is Not Working in IIS

Tags: iis, static, ip, hosting

I'm trying to host the **web application through IIS7** and assigning an Host Name for accessing it.I have an Static IP assigned to my system.

Added an Static IP as well 127.0.0.1 along with host name in etc file and nothing worked out.

For example : If test.com is my Host Name and if i type test.com in browser it should redirect to my local website which i have hosted in IIS7. But it's referring to Online(Internet) and opening some other hosted site

Comment: etc file? Do you mean the hosts file?

Comment: Run the diagnostics and see what it says, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: As far as I know, if you just modify the etc hosts file in your computer. If you access the test.com in the other computer, it will not work well. It will just work well in current computer which hosts file has been modified.

Comment: Yes etc File means the file in Hosts Folder.

Comment: Yes, I have Modified the etc file in Hosts Folder in my Server system. Leave the Other system, **It's not working in the current system(Server System) only**. My End result should be **it should work in the server system as well as the other system to which it's connected to(LAN)**.